# HTTP Sampler to manage iteration for retrieved data(Stored using BeanShell Sampler) from DB

Tags: jmeter

I've created one BeanShell samplet as below, to store retrieved values from DB.

```
ArrayList username = vars.getObject("username");
for (HashMap table : username) {
    for (Object column1 : table.keySet()) {
        log.info(column1 + "=" + table.get(column1));
        String strusername = table.get(column1).toString();
        log.info("Username fethced from DB is=" + strusername);
        vars.put("strusername", new String(strusername));
     }
}
ArrayList password = vars.getObject("password");
for (HashMap table : password) {
    for (Object column2 : table.keySet()) {
        log.info(column2 + "=" + table.get(column2));
        String strpassword = table.get(column2).toString();
        log.info("Password fethced from DB is=" + strpassword);
        vars.put("strpassword", new String(strpassword));
    }
}
```

Here as a output i am getting "String strusername & strpassword" having last retrieved value from DB, but previous values i can see in Jmeter log viewer, but cannot use them to perform login.

Now my query is how could i manage HTTP Sampler to perform login for each set of username, password?

Can you use foreach controller here, if yes what could be structure and where should i use it? or do i need to do modifications in above shown BeanShell Sampler?

Also, is there any way to user multiple variable in foreach controller?

Comment: Answering directly your question, `vars.put("strusername", new String(strusername));` explicitly overwrites previous value of the variable. If you want to save ForEach compatible series, use `vars.put("strusername_" + i, new String(strusername));`, where `i` is index increased on each iteration (1 in first iteration). But script looks unclear: what is the value of variable "username" and why are you trying to parse it as an object? why username and password are looped upon independently (what if they don't match)? etc. So I cannot really be sure if this answer is even correct.

Comment: Thanks but above mentioned solution not working. I am trying to store three multiple raw values for multiple columns(i.e. username,password,etc) and pass them to HTTP Sampler request.

Comment: It was impossible to come to conclusion in your accepted answer from the question you asked. Sorry, but had to vote it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by adding multiple HTTP request to pass data... Actually cookie manager passing same data for same page's post requests & that's why loop/ for each logic controller does not working. Also, if we remove cookie manager then it will not maintain user's session.

So, only solution is to create multiple HTTP sampler for multiple thread(users).

Thanks.